# MQTT over WebSockets using Netty?

Tags: java, websocket, netty, mqtt

I want to use MQTT over Websockets. In Netty using Websockets is quite easy:

```
ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
pipeline.addLast("codec-http", new HttpServerCodec());
pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
pipeline.addLast("handler", new WebSocketServerHandler());
```

I've found MQTT broker  (moquette)  which is based on Netty.

```
 NettyMQTTHandler handler = new NettyMQTTHandler();
 ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(m_bossGroup, m_workerGroup)
             .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) 
             .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() { 
                 @Override
                 public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                    //pipeline.addFirst("metrics", new BytesMetricsHandler(m_metricsCollector));
                    pipeline.addFirst("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, Constants.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT));
                    pipeline.addAfter("idleStateHandler", "idleEventHandler", new MoquetteIdleTimoutHandler());
                    //pipeline.addLast("logger", new LoggingHandler("Netty", LogLevel.ERROR));
                    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new MQTTDecoder());
                    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new MQTTEncoder());
                    pipeline.addLast("metrics", new MessageMetricsHandler(m_metricsCollector));
                    pipeline.addLast("handler", handler);
                 }
             })
             .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
             .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
             .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
```

So in the theory I should be able to send MQTT over Websocket but I have no idea if it possible using Netty? Does any have any clues or ideas how to do that? Should I use MessageToMessageCodec  and BinaryWebSocketFrame?

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me assume your `MQTTDecoder` consumes `ByteBuf`s and produces some MQTT message objects, and `MQTTEncoder` does the opposite, which is usually the case.

Then, the `ByteBuf`s your codec works with is not a Web Socket message.  They need to become the payloads of the Web Socket frames.  I would insert the following handlers into the pipeline:

- A `MessageToMessageDecoder` that transforms a WebSocket text (or binary) frame into a `ByteBuf` so that `MQTTDecoder` can consume it.  The transformation should be very simple - just get the content of the Web Socket frame.
- A `MessageToMessageEncoder` that transforms a `ByteBuf` into a Web Socket text (or binary) frame so that Netty's `WebSocketFrameEncoder` can consume it.  The transformation should also be very simple - just wrap the `ByteBuf` encoded by `MQTTEncoder` with a Web Socket frame object.

The resulting pipeline will look like the following:

1. `HttpResponseEncoder`
2. `HttpRequestDecoder`
3. `HttpObjectAggregator(65536)`
4. `WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/your-websocket-endpoint-path")`
5. `WebSocketFrameToByteBufDecoder` extends `MessageToMessageDecoder`
6. `ByteBufToWebSocketFrameEncoder` extends `MessageToMessageEncoder`
7. `MQTTEncoder`
8. `MQTTDecoder`
9. `MessageMetricsHandler`
10. `handler`

`WebSocketServerProtocolHandler` will perform necessary handshaking with your web socket client and insert `WebSocketFrameEncoder` and `WebSocketFrameDecoder` right before `WebSocketFrameToByteBufDecoder`.  The resulting pipeline after successful handshake will look like the following:

1. `WebSocketFrameEncoder`
2. `WebSocketFrameDecoder`
3. `WebSocketFrameToByteBufDecoder` extends `MessageToMessageDecoder`
4. `ByteBufToWebSocketFrameEncoder` extends `MessageToMessageEncoder`
5. `MQTTEncoder`
6. `MQTTDecoder`
7. `MessageMetricsHandler`
8. `handler`

Comment: Thanks for the clues. I've simply changed MQTTDecoder and MQTTEncoder to MessageToMessageDecoder / MessageToMessageEncoder and it works like a charm ;-)

Code: https://code.google.com/p/moquette-mqtt/issues/attachmentText?id=37&aid=370006000&name=NettyAcceptor.java&token=mb3cYVwbJqfgqAU19vC3QjEqjIw%3A1395163623412

Comment: Yeah, if you have full control over your codec implementation, you can even do that.